# MySQL OptionGroup values, retrieve in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, drupal-8

Using Drupal 8.9.20 and CiviCRM 5.39.1 (on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).
I need to write a query in MySQL to retrieve the values of an optiongroup.

The OptionGroup is used to assign keywords to a contact record and the number of keywords is different for each record.

There are some examples on StackOverflow for how to create a function to split the string but most / all of them require an "index" parameter to indicate which substring you want to pull out after the ASCII 001 character (that Civi uses to separate the values), but I can't find anything that would return all of them.
MySQL returns something like:

```
------------------
+ keywords_56    +
------------------ 
- 63210013056479 -
------------------
```

which in reality is 632 100 130 564 79

Thanks in advance
A.

Comment: What are you trying to have returned from the SQL? Are you looking for the query result to be `632 100 130 564 79`?

Comment: Hi Demerit, this will be a subquerry of a bigger one. These number correspond with desciptions on another table (where the name of the keyword is stored). I need to build a report that displays the title of the publication, the authors, the abstract, the keywords etc. In CiviCRM DB table naming I am trying to pull the values out of the customfield (above) and match them to civicrm_option_value table where field value = 632 (for example). So I guess have a return in rows so I can do a join or some other match. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/8332458 works you just need to have as many "n"s as the maximum number of possible keywords. Below there are 5 but just add more if you need more, e.g. add `union all select 6`. I'd also just slightly change it to add a `WHERE` to remove the extra blanks it creates because civi stores the ascii 1 as bookends, like so:

```
select
  civicrm_value_XXX.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(civicrm_value_XXX.keywords_56, CHAR(1), numbers.n), CHAR(1), -1) singlevalue
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN civicrm_value_XXX
  on CHAR_LENGTH(civicrm_value_XXX.keywords_56)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(civicrm_value_XXX.keywords_56, CHAR(1), ''))>=numbers.n-1
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(civicrm_value_XXX.keywords_56, CHAR(1), numbers.n), CHAR(1), -1) <> ''
order by
  id, n
```